# CMake add_library using the MODULE keyword doesn't create PDB file

Tags: c++, module, cmake, shared-libraries

In my CMake build using ninja as the back-end, DLLs with no exported symbols are always re-linked, so I use the `MODULE` keyword with `add_library` for those DLLs as recommended [here](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15885) and in the [add_library docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_library.html).

But now those DLLs do not have corresponding PDB files created with them (or perhaps they are being generated in the object directory with the default name, rather than in the output directory with the library name).

The [PDB_NAME docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/PDB_NAME.html) imply that it only applies to executables and SHARED libraries (no mention of MODULEs):

> Output name for the ... .pdb file generated by the linker for an
>   executable or shared library target.

How can I get the PDB file created in the expected location with the right name for a MODULE library?

Comment: My alternatives appear to be: 1. add the platform-specific flags to produce the pdb files, or 2. to use the SHARED library type, and add a dummy exported symbol to these libraries so they produce LIB files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to using SHARED libraries and added a dummy symbol to be exported from each such library. This way the cmake files stay consistent with all the other libs.